# Failed to build apk for service app using Kivy Complete VM

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer, pyjnius

I'm trying to build an APK using virtual machine and Kivy Complete VM.
The code is simple, this is the service sample app by Andre Miras: https://github.com/AndreMiras/p4a-service-sticky.
Kivy VM and buildozer.spec were used as-is without any additional configuration.
Seems the issue is related to jnius because I'm able to build apk where it isn't used. Here is a piece of log that might help to figure out what's wrong.
Please advise.

```
[INFO]:    Building pyjnius for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    jnius apparently isn't already in site-packages
[INFO]:    Cythonizing anything necessary in pyjnius
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/kivy/projects/p4a-service-sticky/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/pyjnius-sdl2/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/pyjnius
[INFO]:    -> running python3 -c import sys; print(sys.path)
[INFO]:    Trying first build of pyjnius to get cython files: this is expected to fail                                                                                            
[INFO]:    -> running python3 setup.py build_ext -v
Exception in thread background thread for pid 8308:                                                                                                                               
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/kivy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 1662, in wrap
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kivy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 2606, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/kivy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 2304, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/kivy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 877, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /home/kivy/projects/p4a-service-sticky/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python3 setup.py build_ext -v

  STDOUT:
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 7
1 warning
running build_ext
building 'jnius' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/jnius
/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC -I/home/kivy/projects/p4a-service-sticky/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include -DANDROID -D__ANDROID_API__=21 -I/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -I/home/kivy/projects/p4a-service-sticky/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/include/python3.8 -fPIC -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/include/linux -I/home/kivy/projects/p4a-service-sticky/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/Include -I/home/kivy/projects/p4a-service-sticky/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build -c jnius/jnius.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/jnius/jnius.o
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'jnius/jnius.c'
clang: error: no input files
error: command '/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1


  STDERR:


[INFO]:    pyjnius first build failed (as expected)
[INFO]:    Running cython where appropriate
[INFO]:    Cythonize jnius/jnius.pyx
[INFO]:    -> running python3 -m Cython.Build.Cythonize ./jnius/jnius.pyx

[INFO]:    -> running python3 setup.py build_ext -v                                                                                                                               
           working: error: command '/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1            Exception in thread background thread for pid 8341:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/kivy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 1662, in wrap
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kivy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 2606, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/kivy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 2304, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/kivy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 877, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /home/kivy/projects/p4a-service-sticky/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python3 setup.py build_ext -v

  STDOUT:
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 7
1 warning
running build_ext
building 'jnius' extension
/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC -I/home/kivy/projects/p4a-service-sticky/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include -DANDROID -D__ANDROID_API__=21 -I/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -I/home/kivy/projects/p4a-service-sticky/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/include/python3.8 -fPIC -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/include/linux -I/home/kivy/projects/p4a-service-sticky/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/Include -I/home/kivy/projects/p4a-service-sticky/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build -c jnius/jnius.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/jnius/jnius.o
jnius/jnius.c:3738:89: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'JNIEnv **'
      (aka 'const struct JNINativeInterface_ ***') to parameter of type
      'void **' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  ...(&__pyx_v_env), NULL));
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:10723:19: warning: assigning to 'jchar *' (aka 'unsigned short *')
      from 'const jchar *' (aka 'const unsigned short *') discards qualifiers
      [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
  ...= (__pyx_v_j_env[0])->GetStringChars(__pyx_v_j_env, __pyx_v_j_string, NULL);
     ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:20421:30: warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to
      'jobject' (aka 'struct _jobject *') from 'jobject *' (aka
      'struct _jobject **'); dereference with * [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
          (__pyx_v_jargs[0]) = ((jobject *)__pyx_v_classLoader);
                             ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                               *(                              )
jnius/jnius.c:20430:30: warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to
      'jobject' (aka 'struct _jobject *') from 'jclass *' (aka
      'struct _jobject **'); dereference with * [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
          (__pyx_v_jargs[1]) = __pyx_v_interfaces;
                             ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                               *
jnius/jnius.c:35645:36: warning: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *'
      discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
  (__pyx_v_invoke_methods[0]).name = ((char const *)"invoke0");
                                   ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:35654:41: warning: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *'
      discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
  ...= ((char const *)"(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;");
     ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:51997:258: error: too many arguments to function call, expected
      15, have 16
  ...__Pyx_PyCode_New(0, 0, 0, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_jnius_jnius_env_pxi, __pyx_n_s_detach, 23, __pyx_empty_bytes)...
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/home/kivy/projects/p4a-service-sticky/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note: 
      'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:52009:261: error: too many arguments to function call, expected
      15, have 16
  ...__Pyx_PyCode_New(2, 0, 5, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__62, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_jnius_jnius_export_func_pxi, __pyx_n_s_cast, 4, __pyx_empty_bytes)...
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/home/kivy/projects/p4a-service-sticky/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note: 
      'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:52021:272: error: too many arguments to function call, expected
      15, have 16
  ...__Pyx_PyCode_New(1, 0, 6, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__64, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_jnius_jnius_export_func_pxi, __pyx_n_s_find_javaclass, 17, __pyx_empty_bytes)...
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/home/kivy/projects/p4a-service-sticky/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note: 
      'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:52033:263: error: too many arguments to function call, expected
      15, have 16
  ...__Pyx_PyCode_New(5, 0, 5, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__66, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_jnius_jnius_export_class_pxi, __pyx_n_s_init, 11, __pyx_empty_bytes)...

jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/home/kivy/projects/p4a-service-sticky/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note: 
      'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:52048:273: error: too many arguments to function call, expected
      15, have 16
  ...__Pyx_PyCode_New(2, 0, 12, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__69, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_jnius_jnius_export_class_pxi, __pyx_n_s_instancecheck, 43, __pyx_empty_bytes)...
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/home/kivy/projects/p4a-service-sticky/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note: 
      'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:52060:263: error: too many arguments to function call, expected
      15, have 16
  ...__Pyx_PyCode_New(4, 0, 5, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__71, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_jnius_jnius_export_class_pxi, __pyx_n_s_new, 113, __pyx_empty_bytes)...
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/home/kivy/projects/p4a-service-sticky/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note: 
      'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:52072:273: error: too many arguments to function call, expected
      15, have 16
  ...__Pyx_PyCode_New(2, 0, 8, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__73, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_jnius_jnius_export_class_pxi, __pyx_n_s_subclasscheck, 119, __pyx_empty_bytes)...
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/home/kivy/projects/p4a-service-sticky/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note: 
      'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:52084:273: error: too many arguments to function call, expected
      15, have 16
  ...__Pyx_PyCode_New(1, 0, 1, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__75, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_jnius_jnius_export_class_pxi, __pyx_n_s_get_javaclass, 148, __pyx_empty_bytes)...
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/home/kivy/projects/p4a-service-sticky/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note: 
      'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:52096:274: error: too many arguments to function call, expected
      15, have 16
  ...__Pyx_PyCode_New(2, 0, 21, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__77, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_jnius_jnius_export_class_pxi, __pyx_n_s_resolve_class, 152, __pyx_empty_bytes)...
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/home/kivy/projects/p4a-service-sticky/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note: 
      'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:52108:280: error: too many arguments to function call, expected
      15, have 16
  ...__Pyx_PyCode_New(2, 0, 3, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS|CO_VARKEYWORDS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__79, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_jnius_jnius_export_class_pxi, __pyx_n_s_init, 1051, __pyx_empty_bytes)...
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/home/kivy/projects/p4a-service-sticky/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note: 
      'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:52120:280: error: too many arguments to function call, expected
      15, have 16
  ...__Pyx_PyCode_New(2, 0, 3, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS|CO_VARKEYWORDS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__81, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_jnius_jnius_export_class_pxi, __pyx_n_s_init, 1057, __pyx_empty_bytes)...
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/home/kivy/projects/p4a-service-sticky/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note: 
      'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:52140:255: error: too many arguments to function call, expected
      15, have 16
  ...__Pyx_PyCode_New(3, 0, 3, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__84, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_jnius_jnius_proxy_pxi, __pyx_n_s_init, 2, __pyx_empty_bytes)...
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/home/kivy/projects/p4a-service-sticky/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note: 
      'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:52155:256: error: too many arguments to function call, expected
      15, have 16
  ...__Pyx_PyCode_New(3, 0, 3, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__87, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_jnius_jnius_proxy_pxi, __pyx_n_s_get_2, 7, __pyx_empty_bytes)...
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/home/kivy/projects/p4a-service-sticky/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note: 
      'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:52167:256: error: too many arguments to function call, expected
      15, have 16
  ...__Pyx_PyCode_New(2, 0, 2, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__89, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_jnius_jnius_proxy_pxi, __pyx_n_s_call, 10, __pyx_empty_bytes)...
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/home/kivy/projects/p4a-service-sticky/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note: 
      'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:52232:259: error: too many arguments to function call, expected
      15, have 16
  ...__Pyx_PyCode_New(3, 0, 5, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__96, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_stringsource, __pyx_n_s_pyx_unpickle_Enum, 1, __pyx_empty_bytes)...
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/home/kivy/projects/p4a-service-sticky/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note: 
      'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:57497:9: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 15,
      have 16
        __pyx_empty_bytes  /*PyObject *lnotab*/
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/home/kivy/projects/p4a-service-sticky/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note: 
      'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
6 warnings and 16 errors generated.
error: command '/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1


  STDERR:


[INFO]:    STDOUT (last 20 lines of 213):
    jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'  
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)   
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~    
/home/kivy/projects/p4a-service-sticky/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note:     
      'PyCode_New' declared here    
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(  
           ^    
jnius/jnius.c:57497:9: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 15, 
      have 16   
        __pyx_empty_bytes  /*PyObject *lnotab*/ 
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'  
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)   
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~    
/home/kivy/projects/p4a-service-sticky/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note:     
      'PyCode_New' declared here    
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(  
           ^    
6 warnings and 16 errors generated. 
error: command '/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
[INFO]:    STDERR:

[INFO]:    COMMAND:
cd /home/kivy/projects/p4a-service-sticky/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/pyjnius-sdl2/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/pyjnius && /home/kivy/projects/p4a-service-sticky/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python3 setup.py build_ext -v

[WARNING]: ERROR: /home/kivy/projects/p4a-service-sticky/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python3 failed!
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/kivy/projects/p4a-service-sticky/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to uninstall all local user cython installations and install cython using sudo pip install cython==version. https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/issues/731

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Cython locally first.

```
sudo pip install cython==version
```